# Find the sum of the specific column with a numpy array containing strings?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the sum for the 2nd column in my array. The following code I have is:

```
import numpy
x = numpy.array([['Physics', 10],['Gravity', 9.81],['Euler', 2.71],['Force', 6],['Mass', 12],['Torque', 8],['pi', 3.14],['Frequency', 2],['Wavelength', 3],['Velocity', 6]])
print(sum(x[:,1]))
```

I obtain the following error code:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'numpy.str_'

Tried inquiring about the error codes with little success. The column specified is a column of numbers. I'm confused as to why the code is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that the start value for `sum` is `0`, from the documentation:

> Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of
>   numbers

So as you have strings in your array the dtype is `U10`,

```
print(x.dtype)  # U10
```

So `sum` attempts to add and integer and a string hence the error, to avoid it you could do cast it to float and then sum,  for instance like this:

```
import numpy

x = numpy.array(
    [['Physics', 10], ['Gravity', 9.81], ['Euler', 2.71], ['Force', 6], ['Mass', 12], ['Torque', 8], ['pi', 3.14],
     ['Frequency', 2], ['Wavelength', 3], ['Velocity', 6]])
print(x[:, 1].astype(numpy.float).sum())
```

**Output**

```
62.660000000000004
```

Given that your array have mixed types you need to cast it to float.

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic approach

```
sum(np.array(x[:,1],dtype=float))
```